# Generating SSH keys between git local and remote repository over proxy

Tags: linux, git, ssh, proxy

I am using CentOS7.
I have tried to set connection between my local git repository and remote git repository on github.com. But my local repository is at work and it is behind the proxy.
I have found a lot of answers on stackoverflow about this problem. Maybe I am not so attentive and so on...but I haven't resolved my problem yet.
My steps were:

> 1. Creation of repository at github.com
> 2. Generating SSH keys using this tutorial https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/
>      But on "Step 5: Test the connection" in link-tutorial after using command `ssh -T git@github.com`
>      I was a little bit confused. 
>      Connection did not work and I got this error:
>      `ssh: Could not resolve hostname github.com: Name or service not known`
>      Blockquote

At first I tried to set proxy in git config file: 
`git config --global http.proxy http://http://192.168.32.2:3128` But  the result was the same I couldn't connect to my remote repository.

> Next step was to set address of github.com in /etc/hosts as : `192.30.252.0 github.com` 
>   Address for github.com I took from here https://help.github.com/articles/what-ip-addresses-does-github-use-that-i-should-whitelist/.
>   After using command `ssh -T git@github.com` everything just hang up.

Despite the fact that connection through ssh did not work I tried to clone repository from my remote github account to my local account at work: `git clone https://github.com/Nit84/hello-world.git`. And everything copied as it should be and without any password.
At this point I just got stack. And I haven't the faintest idea what to do further.

> Here is a list of my configurations using `git config --list`:

```
[root@localhost hello-world]# git config --list
user.name=Nit84
user.email=blob@gmail.com
core.editor=vim
http.proxy=http://192.168.32.2:3128
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
remote.origin.url=ssh://git@github.com/Nit84/hello-world.git
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
branch.master.remote=origin
branch.master.merge=refs/heads/master
```

and here is the verbose mode of `ssh -vT git@github.com`:

```
[root@localhost hello-world]# ssh -vT github.com
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /root/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 56: Applying options for *
ssh: Could not resolve hostname github.com: Name or service not known
```

Is there any way to resolve my problem with connection between git local and remote repository using ssh-keys over proxy? Simply saying I want my command `ssh -T git@github.com` works as it is described in [genereting ssh keys](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/)

Comment: You probably need to set up ssh to use your proxy aswell. See `man ssh_config` (for `~/.ssh/config`) and search for `ProxyCommand`.

Comment: your problem is DNS over proxy